# How can I send emails of matching filenames to dataframe values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, email, smtplib

I'm interested in sending  emails  via  smtplib package based on the below conditions:-

1. Emails and names of files are in a spreadsheet. They are as below:-

```
Name Email
1001 xx@gmail.com   
1002 yy@xxx.com
1003 zz@yyy.com
```

The "Name" column name should  match files in a folder.
2. Main idea is to compare filenames in the folder to the  name in the spreadsheet and if a match exists, then the file in the folder is sent to a matching email address.
For example, if  1001.csv and 1002.csv exist in the folder, then 1001.csv will be  sent to xx@gmail.com and 1002.csv sent to yy@xxx.com.

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

# Spreadsheet with emails and  names
email_list = pd.read_excel(r'xxxxx\Email.xlsx')
files1 = glob.glob('Folder_xxx/*.xlsx') #Folder with files to be sent as attachments

# getting the names and the emails
names = email_list['Name']
emails = email_list['Email']
 
for i in range(len(emails)): # iterate through the records
 
    # for every record get the name and the email addresses
    name = names[i]
    email = emails[i]
   
    #Some  help needed from here I believe
    while name == os.path.xxxx:
         smtp_ssl_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
         smtp_ssl_port = 465
         email_from = "xxx@xxx.com"
         email_pass = "xxxx"
         email_to = email

         filename = (filename)+.csv #Get the filename  matching the name in the while condition. Help on this.
         msg2 = MIMEMultipart()
         msg2['Subject'] = "Present Record(s)"
         msg2['From'] = email_from
         msg2['To'] = email
         fo=open(filename,'rb')
         attach = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(fo.read(),_subtype="xlsx")
         fo.close()
         attach.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=filename)
         msg.attach(attach)
         s2 = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_ssl_host, smtp_ssl_port)
         s2.login(email_from, email_pass)  
         s2.send_message(msg)
         s2.quit()
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if files are in the same folder, you can try something like this

```
import os
from collections import ChainMap
folder_path="." # your folder path
my_files=[{each_file.split(".")[0]:each_file} for each_file in os.listdir(folder_path) if each_file.endswith(".csv")]
my_files_dict = dict(ChainMap(*my_files))
```

and then in your for loop:

```
if my_files_dict.get(name):
    print(f"file found:{my_files_dict.get(name)}") # attach this file : my_files_dict.get(name)
```

Comment: Thank you @simpleApp. The first part is fine and  maps the  output to a dictionary as below:{'1004': '1004.xlsx', '1003': '1003.xlsx', '1002': '1002.xlsx', '1001': '1001.xlsx'}. The if my_files_dict.get(name) returns  nothing  even  with print(f"file found:{my_files_dict.get(name)}"). Probably the  Get function is not working  as expected?

Comment: get on dictionary return the value if the key is found, otherwise, it returns None. So if your key is not found it will not go into if condition. as keys are '1004' or '1003', they are string, so you need to put get on with string value. If your excel is giving you int, pls type cast it to string. something like this `my_number=1002
my_string_number=str(my_number)
print(f"my_number class is : {type(my_number)},my_string_number class is : {type(my_string_number)}")`

Comment: Thank you @simpleApp for the response. Tried it as below. Typecasting gets the records excel files. I used for i in range(len(emails)): 
    name = str(names[i])
    email = emails[i]  filename = my_files_dict.get(name) 
     attach =email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(filename.read(),_subtype="xlsx") . I get the error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mime'. Any idea on this?

Comment: your this line `email = emails[i]` has overwritten the email lib, so pls change something like this 'my_email = emails[i]' @Herdil  - I hope this will fix this.

Comment: You are right @simpleApp. Fixed it and  it works.