# How to attach a file into a email with python?

Tags: python, mime

I'm trying to automate the sending of billing emails to customers and mining the internet I managed to reach this result. The application consists of entering a spreadsheet, checking customers with open fees, saving to a dictionary and sending a reminder email. However I want to add an attachment with the payment slip as well, but I was not successful. I tried to use  `askopenfilename` but it only sends the file name in the email and not the attachment.

Here is the code below:

```py
import openpyxl, smtplib, sys
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


# Opens the spreadsheet and obtains the status of the last payment.

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/temp/cobranca.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

lastCol = sheet.max_column
# latestMonth = sheet.cell(row=1, column=lastCol).value

# Checks the payment status of each customer.

unpaidMembers = {}
for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    for c in range(3, lastCol + 1):
        payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value
        if payment != 'ok':
            client = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
            email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
            month = sheet.cell(row=1, column=c).value
            unpaidMembers[client] = email
            print('Row:', r, 'Column:', c, 'Client:', client, 'Email:', email, 'Month:', month)

# Log in to your email account.

for client, email, in unpaidMembers.items():
    body = "client: %s | month: %s" % (client, month)
    print('sending email to %s...' % (email))

    # create message object instance
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    # setup the parameters of the message
    password = "password"
    msg['From'] = "email@email.com"
    msg['To'] = email
    msg['Subject'] = "%s - Open honorary." % (client)

    # add in the message body
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body))
    msg.attach(MIMEText(askopenfilename()))

    # create server
    server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.omnia.net.br: 587')

    server.starttls()

    # Login Credentials for sending the mail
    server.login(msg['From'], password)

    # send the message via the server.
    server.sendmail(msg['From'], email, msg.as_string())

server.quit()

messagebox.showinfo("System Message", "Reminders sent successfully.")
print("successfully sent email to %s:" % (email))
```

Spreadsheet model used: https://prnt.sc/1297huw

Comment: please see if this helps [send an email with xls as attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67253333/how-can-i-send-emails-of-matching-filenames-to-dataframe-values-in-python/67253679#67253679)

Comment: This may be labouring the obvious, but a spreadsheet is not text. You should be doing `msg.attach(email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(filecontents))`.

Comment: I think I expressed myself badly, my only need is to be able to attach a file, I put the template in the spreadsheet only if they want to test the code on their respective machines.

Answer (score 0):

The MIME standards require that you declare the type of the attached file. For an xlsx file, it should be application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, for a binary file with no more precision, you can always use application/octet-stream (the default for `MIMEApplication`). You can find other types on [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types).

And you must pass the byte content of the file and not its name:

```
...
msg.attach(MIMEApplication(open('foobar.xlsx', 'rb').read(),
                           'vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument'
                           '.spreadsheetml.sheet'))
# or
# msg.attach(MIMEApplication(open('foobar.bin', 'rb').read()))
...
```

And as you already have a true `Message` object, you should better use `send_message`:

```
...
server.send_message(msg)
...
```